# Divide page with iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Hello I am new developer in Korea.

I do not speak English. ... As of this writing.So there may be a mistranslation. (T.T)

I was wondering.If you look at the images on the current page via Google API script injection screen two of the iframe or the area, adding to the'd like to share a Google developer tools like...

Is It Possible?

Thank you obtain the advice of senior developers worldwide nimdeul ... ^^

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try frameset insead...

for example:

```
<frameset cols="25%,*,25%">
  <frame src="frame_a.htm">
  <frame src="frame_b.htm">
  <frame src="frame_c.htm">
</frameset>
```

*(though its not supported in html5)*

Comment: Thank you, but that's not the answer I want ..^^